# How to add meta tag for Social Media in nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

- I have some api, that response `{title: '', img: '', description: ''}`
- Here is my code in component

```
...
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('call_api', ['meta']),
},
 head() {
    return {
        meta: [
          { hid: 'title', name: 'title', content: this.meta.title },
          {
            hid: 'og:title',
            name: 'og:title',
            property: 'og:title',
            content: this.meta.title,
          },
          {
            hid: 'og:description',
            name: 'og:description',
            property: 'og:description',
            content: this.meta.description,
          },
          {
            hid: 'og:image',
            property: 'og:image',
            content: this.meta.img,
          },
        ],
      }
  },
...
```

- When i add link on facebook, linkedin, .... I get some default values from nuxt ,not from my data.

Comment: When is your HTTP call made? Are you using `ssr: true`?

Comment: @kissu yess, i am using `ssr: true`, i call api inside `created` func?

Comment: Try in `asyncData()` rather.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work @kissu